# Incomplete .prj file created when .mxd is opened

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, prj

I have a single .mxd file that, when opened, creates a projection file (.prj) in the same folder as the .mxd file. This does not happen with other .mxd files.

This projection file is called ".prj" (not including the quotation marks).

[image]

The .mxd file's data frames (2) also have CRS defined (same for both).

However, the ".prj" file does not contain the typical WKT and EPSG information (I half expected it to include the information relevant to the CRS's in defined in the .mxd file). Instead, it just shows the following...

```
Projection    GEOGRAPHIC
Datum         NAD83
Spheroid      GRS80
Units         DD
Zunits        NO
Parameters
```

...which seems to me like a broken projection file.

What setting is turned on in this .mxd that makes this happen?

Comment: That's...odd. That's the format for a GRID or coverage data format which uses a different style for a coordinate reference system. If it was tied to data it would be in the data's folder as a prj.adf file.

Comment: lol
yeah. very odd. i think it would actually be a pretty cool if arcmap DID export a .prj when the dataframe was assigned a CRS. 
There don't seem to be any downsides so far; just an oddity.